# xamarin.forms set thickness in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following XAML:

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo"
    x:Class="Foo.MainPage">
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>0, 20, 0, 0</OnPlatform.iOS>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Padding>
<StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"
             HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <BoxView Color="Green"
             Opacity="{Binding Value}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Value,
           StringFormat='Value is {0:F2}' }"
           Opacity="{Binding Value }"/>
    <Slider x:Name="slider"/>
</StackLayout>
```

It is attempting - and failing - to set the padding to 20 pixels at the top on iOS. Perfectly straightforward, exactly as suggested online - does not work. The padding is still clearly 0 - see below. I really cannot see what the issue would be - this is a completely reasonable bit of XAML, and before you ask, no, something like:

```
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="0, 20, 0, 0" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Padding>
```

does not work either. The generated code:

```
// MainPage.xaml.g.cs

[global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("MainPage.xaml")]
public partial class MainPage : global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage {

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
    private global::Xamarin.Forms.Slider slider;

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
    private void InitializeComponent() {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MainPage));
        slider = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.Slider>(this, "slider");
    }
}
```

Image:

[image]

Any suggestions? For what it's worth, I know I can override OnAppearance in C#, but I'm trying to follow better practice by keeping appearance in XAML and logic in C#, which this is making unnecessarily difficult. I really wish XAML were better documented, that issues like this were caught at compile-time, and the code in the docs actually did what it says it does :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The padding you are trying to handle is controlled by iOS + Xamarin.Forms, called [Safe Area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout) and you can control it by asking `Xamarin.Forms` to take this area into account:

```
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
```

[image]

```
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Foo"
    x:Class="Foo.MainPage"
    xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
    BackgroundColor="Yellow">    
    <StackLayout BindingContext="{x:Reference slider}"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 BackgroundColor="Blue">
        <BoxView Color="Green"
                 Opacity="{Binding Value}"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding Value,
               StringFormat='Value is {0:F2}' }"
               Opacity="{Binding Value }"/>
        <Slider x:Name="slider"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Excellent! Solves for the notch, and on my machine does actually add the padding. Excellent job. Perhaps Xamarin gets confused between the safe area and universal padding. In any case you've given a nice solution. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around, I've realised this is an actual bug: the problem goes away when you set the second value to anything other than 20.

...why on Earth **that** is a bug, I will likely never know. Anyone reading this, you are more than welcome to correct me/give a better answer.

Comment: this works fine for me, for any value including 20.  Using XF 3.6.0.344457

Comment: I'm using XF 4.0.0.482894, so maybe that's why? I'm on a Mac as well to be fair

Comment: if you think you've found a bug file it on the XF Github

Comment: I would like to know why this answer was down-voted. It is an answer, albeit not a nice one, and one that reveals the underlying problem is very likely an actual bug, which I'll be reporting. To whoever downvoted - unless it's Alexey - I hope your code breaks.